# Find Pattern Matching every column in excel, output as number of time repeating

Tags: r, excel, pattern-matching, vba

I have excel file full of alphabets which is `"a","b","c"` only. There are total 20 columns and 300 rows. I just wanted to find pattern matching in all columns. For example, if i search for 4 rows of pattern matching where there is `"aabc","bcdb"` and etc the output will be how many times the same pattern repeat from the csv file. If i search for 5 rows of pattern matching where there is `"abcaa", "bbaca"` and etc  the output will be how many times the same pattern repeat from the csv file. It is not necessary that the matching must be in same rows. If the string pattern occur anywhere else in the file can be considered too. The output may be in the next sheet should be fine.  I have tried in VBA and R using `Regex` but only counting single cell. Any advice on how to find the pattern matching from the excel file would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Excel File:

```
    **A         B         C          D**
1     a     |   a     |   a      |   b    |
2     a     |   a     |   a      |   c    |    
3     b     |   b     |   b      |   a    |
4     c     |   c     |   c      |   c    |
5     d     |   b     |   d      |   b    |
6     b     |   a     |   b      |   c    |   
7     b     |   b     |   b      |   b    |
8     a     |   a     |   a      |   c    |
9     a     |   c     |   a      |   a    |
10    c     |   c     |   c      |   c    |     
11    c     |   a     |   c      |   c    |
12    a     |   a     |   a      |   a    |
13    b     |   b     |   a      |   b    |
14    b     |   b     |   b      |   a    |
15    c     |   c     |   c      |   c    |
```

Output Example:
If search for 4 rows

- aabc 3
- dbba 2
- baac 2
- so on...

---

If search for 5 rows

- aabcd 2
- aacca 3
- so on..

Comment: It is not clear based on the description

Comment: It has been edited now

Comment: It is not clear `aabc 3`

Comment: aabc repeated for 3 times in the file because it search for 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In **E1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:D1)
```

and copy down.  Then copy column **E** and *PasteSpecialValues* into column **F**.
Then apply *RemoveDuplicates* to column **F**.
Then in **G1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,F1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: It supposed to be based on rows. What we get from the code is column. CountIf basically apply for single channel. What i need is any 4 rows have the same match string with other string in the cell will appear as match and number of times. Based on the excel file, if we make 4 string cell then there are few and just take "acaa" match in (A9:A12, B8:B11,C9:C12,D9:D12) and if if it matches in anywhere like for example E14:E17, F20:F23. Then will have number of time it repeats. I`m doing in VBA and in R. The formula such as countIF and match not work for this.